# Is there any other term in usage for book mark?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context

A piece of a fabric, leather ,paper is called book mark.Is there any other term used instead? Secondly how to ask someone to book mark a page?

Comment: _Bookmark_ is usually written as one word. You could use _marker_, but that isn't specific to books.

Comment: Here at Stack Exchange, you can set a *bookmark* on any question you want to have remembered, so you can easily refer back to it at a later date. That used to be called marking a question as one of your *favourites*, but the wording changed just last week. Here, it's not physical. I suppose it could be called a *reference* or *reminder*.